# Rendering image with textview

Tags: ios, swift

I am placing a textview on a image. With following code:

```
var previewImageView=UIImageView()
self.previewImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
self.view.addSubview(self.previewImageView)
textField = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 50, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 36))
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
self.view.addSubview(textField)
```

It works well. But I want to render this image with textview. Then I will save it to gallery.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I tried following code but it is only rendering image not textview:

```
//Setup the image context using the passed image.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)



//Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

// Creating a point within the space that is as bit as the image.
var rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

//Now Draw the text into an image.
drawText.drawRect(rect)

// Create a new image out of the images we have created
var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

// End the context now that we have the image we need
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

//And pass it back up to the caller.
return newImage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can render whole view into an UIImage using CGGraphicsContext. Here is an example of the code:

```
func imageWithView(view: UIView!) -> UIImage! {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

When you pass scale = 0.0 it will take a scale of your screen.

An example of usage:

```
let image = imageWithView(view)
```

Code to save image:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

More information about UIGraphicsContext and image saving can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html).

**Update:**

If you want to render only specific views, then you should use *CALayer*, *renderInContext*. When you use *renderInContext* it does not know views.frame and draws at (0:0) in coordinate system, so you should use CGContextTranslateCTM to move coordinate system.

To render only these two views you can do:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, previewImageView.frame.origin.x, previewImageView.frame.origin.y)
previewImageView.layer.renderInContext(context)
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, textField.frame.origin.x - previewImageView.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y - previewImageView.frame.origin.y)
textField.layer.renderInContext(context)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Please set opaque true/false as you need. When I was testing in playground I was using not opaque views.

**Update 2:**

Code which should work in all scenarios:

```
func imageFromViews(views: [UIView]!, contextSize: CGSize!) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contextSize, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    for view in views {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y)
        view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -view.frame.origin.x, -view.frame.origin.y)
    }

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have a save image button over the image. I don't want this button in image.

Comment: I tried your updated code. But image variable looks nil.

Comment: Is context nil as well? What is view.bounds.size?

Comment: view.bounds.size: (320.0, 568.0)

Comment: Did you move this code to a different func? Can you check _UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()_ value before _UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()_?

Comment: I am checking it. By the way can you check my question again? I updated it.

Comment: Yes, here is a code to draw textView and imageView: `CGContextTranslateCTM(context, previewImageView.frame.origin.x, previewImageView.frame.origin.y) previewImageView.layer.renderInContext(context) CGContextTranslateCTM(context, textField.frame.origin.x - previewImageView.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y - previewImageView.frame.origin.y) textField.layer.renderInContext(context)`

Comment: As i said, it returns nil image.

Comment: This one works for me fine: http://pastebin.com/qSWK2AMm, and the one I sent to you works fine. Can you please send whole method code in pastebin?

Comment: It worked. But do you know why it looks like this? http://prntscr.com/89k6h5 it is a 2448x3264 but real image is too small.

Comment: Wrong context size probably. I would prefer to initialize context using: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0) + check bounds.size before initializing. Did you move everything to a separate method?

Comment: But you should create custom method, the one I gave is just an example. You should create something like `func renderView(view1: UIView!, view2: UIView!, inContextWithSize size: CGSize!) -> UIImage`

Comment: Thank you, it works well now. Please edit your answer with your updated code.

Comment: What did you do? which one did you use?

Comment: I have added one more update to my answer with more reusable code, so you can use it if you need.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything.